# Regex code to catch whatsapp messages with dates inclusive

Tags: python, regex

I have written a python script to analyze a WhatsApp group chat log being sent out and automatically extract the data I need to google sheets. I used Regex to separate date+time+sender from the message:

`^(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d,.*?)(?=^^\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d|\Z)`.

I also tried a suggestion on stack overflow:

```
^
(?P<datetime>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}[^-]+)\s+-\s+
(?P<name>[^:]+):\s+
(?P<message>[\s\S]+?)
(?=^\d{2}|\Z)
```

Both expressions work fine until the message includes a typed date. is there a way to get around this?

A snippet of the text string:

```
03/01/2021, 10:06 - Messages and calls are end-to-end encrypted. No one outside of this chat, not even WhatsApp, can read or listen to them. Tap to learn more.
21/06/2018, 07:47 - +234 806 679 5599 created group "Keremor Barging"
03/01/2021, 08:48 - John C. added you
03/01/2021, 08:49 - +234 703 803 5040: Waiting for this message
04/01/2021, 08:06 - +234 703 803 5040:Ugo-Ocha Terminal.           

No STS operation was carried out.

Total volume Onboard Ugo Ocha As at 0800hrs 04/01/2021 remain the same
```

Comment: Can you indicate what your RE does when there is a date in the message?

Comment: And also, what would you want to obtain on that last block of five lines? One 5-line message?

Comment: You should present your anticipated input and make note of irregularities and also present your desired output/matches. As it stands, it's very difficult to guess your desired outcome.

Comment: At any rate, the regex works for dates in the message body so your question is faulty. https://regex101.com/r/Rm8u4j/1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thanks for the comment. I realized my test string was not accurate. https://regex101.com/r/lvV8gR/1. The link shows the problem.

Comment: @joanis. I am new to Stack overflow so I am still trying to understand how to ask better questions. Here's a link showing what the problem is. https://regex101.com/r/lvV8gR/1. Whenever there is a date following a new line. The regex fails to get the string after this date. That is my problem

Comment: So if I understand correctly, every time a line starts with a date, that's a record you want to identify, and it should include all subsequent lines until the next line that starts with a data. This might be doable with an RE, but I would suggest reading your input file one line a a time, and have an inner loop that reads those extra lines until the next date. That would be much, much simpler than trying to do it with an RE.

Comment: Mind you, this seems to work: `^(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d,.*?)(?=^\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d,|\Z)` I removed the doubled `^` from yours, and added `,` on the look-ahead, so it's the same as the first part, and it matches all the text in your example.

Comment: Thank you Joanis. Your regex suggestion works exactly as I wanted. I will try the other method though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

input = """
03/01/2021, 10:06 - Messages and calls are end-to-end encrypted. No one outside of this chat, not even WhatsApp, can read or listen to them. Tap to learn more.
21/06/2018, 07:47 - +234 806 679 5599 created group "Keremor Barging"
03/01/2021, 08:48 - John C. added you
03/01/2021, 08:49 - +234 703 803 5040: Waiting for this message
04/01/2021, 08:06 - +234 703 803 5040:Ugo-Ocha Terminal.    
"""

r1 = r"([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4},\s+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\s+\-\s+(\+[0-9\s]+[0-9]{1}):?\s*([^$]+)$"
r2 = r"([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4},\s+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\s+\-\s+([^$]+)$"

lines = re.compile(r"\n").split(input)
for line in lines:
    if line!= '':
        m = re.match(r1, line)
        if m:
            print("<datetime>"+m.group(1)+"<phone>"+m.group(2)+"<message>"+m.group(3))
        else:
            m = re.match(r2, line)
            if m:
                print("<datetime>"+m.group(1)+"<message>"+m.group(2))
```

Something like this, there is 2 kind of message types:

1. With phone numbers => r1
2. Without phone numbers => r2

output:

```
<datetime>03/01/2021, 10:06<message>Messages and calls are end-to-end encrypted. No one outside of this chat, not even WhatsApp, can read or listen to them. Tap to learn more.
<datetime>21/06/2018, 07:47<phone>+234 806 679 5599<message>created group "Keremor Barging"
<datetime>03/01/2021, 08:48<message>John C. added you
<datetime>03/01/2021, 08:49<phone>+234 703 803 5040<message>Waiting for this message
<datetime>04/01/2021, 08:06<phone>+234 703 803 5040<message>Ugo-Ocha Terminal.
```

Edit: try with this one, added comma optional

```
^(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d,?.*?)(?=^^\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d|\Z)
```

Comment: Hello Zital, Here's a link to the problem. https://regex101.com/r/lvV8gR/1

Comment: @EbenezarOkezie-Alaukwu the comma is optional, try this: https://regex101.com/r/KZtIw4/1